# Parameter as object item?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, this

Ok so noob question here, but what I'm trying to do looks something like this:

```
var statShow = function(stat) {
  playerSats.stat = stat;
  console.log("Your "+stat+" is "+this.(this.stat)+"!");
};
playerStats.statShow = statShow;
playerStats.statShow("intel");
```

I'm trying to get the parameter for the function as the item  want to retrieve in the object, but when I simply type:

```
this.stat
```

It searches for an item (in the object playerSats) called stat, not an item called intel (Which was my parameter). Please help!

P.S. Here's my object:

```
var playerStats = {
  playerLvl: 1,
  power: strength,
  intel: intelligence,
  sped: speed
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var statShow = function(stat) {
      console.log("Your "+stat+" is "+this[stat]+"!");
 };
 playerStats.statShow = statShow;
 playerStats.statShow("intel");
```

Moreover why are you doing this: `playerSats.stat = stat;` ?

Comment: It's my method for displaying stats.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use bracket notation for objects:

```
var statShow = function(stat) {
  this[stat] = stat;
  console.log("Your "+stat+" is "+this[stat]+"!");
};
playerStats.statShow = statShow;
playerStats.statShow("intel");
```

I am confused why you would want to do this, though, as you just have set your `property name` and `value` to the same value... Which means you won't even see the difference.

Comment: I was wondering in the this[stat] = stat as well, in this case you would be setting the stat to stat, no (or better said this["intel"] = "intel")? I left it out in my answer because I thought it was the wrong approach here ;)

Comment: Yeah I saw, it's true, but I find it more poignant to add it and then comment on the strangeness. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties on javascript objects with `object[propertyName]` style syntax.

To use it in your current setup, it would be enough to use

```
var statShow = function(stat) {
  console.log("Your "+stat+" is "+this[stat]+"!");
};

playerStats.statShow = statShow;
playerStats.statShow("intel");
```